# Error Handling section codes execution in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Writing a macro program, in that I need to show custom error message if error occurs, I'm facing a problem here. Error handing is working correctly. but the codes in error handling section are executing even though the error not occurred

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
Source_File_Path = "G:\" & Source_File_name & ".csv"
Open Source_File_Path For Input As #1
On Error GoTo 0
.
.
.
ErrorHandling:
Worksheets("REPORT_VIEW").Activate
MsgBox "FILE NOT FOUND"
```

I'm seeing the "FILE NOT FOUND" Error on every time.
Help Me., Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an Exit sub statement (or Exit Function if you code is from a function). for instance:

```
sub MySub()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    Source_File_Path = "G:\" & Source_File_name & ".csv"
    Open Source_File_Path For Input As #1
    On Error GoTo 0
    .
    .
Exit sub 
    ErrorHandling:
    Worksheets("REPORT_VIEW").Activate
    MsgBox "FILE NOT FOUND"

end sub
```